# Выборочная активация чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Всем здравствуйте.

**Условие.**

Есть первый блок, в нем три чекбокса:

```
<input id="enableOne" type="checkbox" />1 разряд<br />
<input id="enableTwo" type="checkbox" />2 разряд<br />
<input id="enableNo" type="checkbox" />Нет разряда<br />
```

Есть второй блок, в нем несколько деактивированных (disabled) чекбоксов:

```
<input class="check" id="1" type="checkbox" />1<br />
<input class="check" id="2" type="checkbox" />2<br />
<input class="check" id="3" type="checkbox" />3<br />
<input class="check" id="4" type="checkbox" />4<br />
<input class="check" id="5" type="checkbox" />5<br />
```

**Задача.**

Надо, чтобы при выборе одного из чекбоксов в первом блоке активировались (включалась возможность ставить галочки) привязанные к нему чебоксы во втором блоке. Например, при выборе "1 разряд" активируются 1-5 чекбоксы, "2 разряд" - 1,2  и 3 чекбоксы и т.д. Т.е. человек, выбрав свой разряд, может отмечать только чекбоксы, привязанные к этому разряду. Потому надо к каждому чекбоксу из первого блока привязать определенные чекбоксы во втором блоке по "id".

Если человек снимает галочку в первом блоке, то выбранные чекбоксы во втором блоке должны очиститься и деактивироваться.

На просторах интернета нашел скрипт, который позволяет отметив один чекбокс включить другие. Код ниже:

```
<input id="enableAll" type="checkbox" />000
<input class="check" type="checkbox" />1
<input class="check" type="checkbox" />2
<input class="check" type="checkbox" />3

$(function(){
$("input.check").attr("disabled","disabled");
$("input#enableAll").click(
function(){
if($(this)[0].checked==false) $("input.check").attr("disabled","disabled")
else $("input.check").removeAttr("disabled")
}
)
}
)
```

Как его можно переделать под мою задачу? Ибо в JS не разбираюсь. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: для начала вам надо описать каким-либо образом, какие зависимые чекбоксы должны проставляться. Можно решение унифицировать, либо если набор чекбоксов строго ограничен, то написать в лоб.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение представлено тут: https://jsfiddle.net/58sckfp6/

```
<input class="control" id="enableOne" data-type="one" type="checkbox" />1 разряд<br />
<input class="control" id="enableTwo" data-type="two" type="checkbox" />2 разряд<br />
<input class="control" id="enableNo" data-type="three" type="checkbox" />Нет разряда<br />
<hr>
<input class="check one" id="1" type="checkbox" />1<br />
<input class="check one two" id="2" type="checkbox" />2<br />
<input class="check two three" id="3" type="checkbox" />3<br />
<input class="check three" id="4" type="checkbox" />4<br />
<input class="check one two three" id="5" type="checkbox" />5<br />
```

---

```
$('.control').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $('.check.'+$(this).attr('data-type')).prop('checked',true);
    }
})
```

Теперь подробно: в первых (управляющих) чекбоксах мы добавляем атрибут, по которому будем идентифицировать чекбоксы из второй группы (управляемые). Чекбоксы с классом, соответствующим атрибуту `data-type` чекбокса, на который кликнули, будут отмечены.

---

**UPD:** по изменениям в вопросе. Чтобы деактивировать чекбокс достаточно дописать к нему атрибут `disabled`.
В обработчике у нас есть проверка, был ли управляющий чекбокс "чекнут". Чтобы отключить и деактивировать управляемые чекбоксы, надо дописать блок `else` в это условие:

```
$('.control').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
    $('.check.'+$(this).attr('data-type')).removeAttr('disabled');
  }else{
    $('.check.'+$(this).attr('data-type'))
            .prop('checked',false)
            .attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
})
```

Обновлённый фиддл: https://jsfiddle.net/58sckfp6/3/

Comment: Я, наверно, плохо задачу объяснил. Текст вопроса поправил.

Comment: @alegraft, а что поменялось? и чем не подходят указанные решения?

Answer (score 2):

Можно привязать `id` первой группы `checkbox` ко второй с помощью добавления классов(по названию `id`) в нужные `checkbox` второй группы:

```js
$(".checktype").change(function() {
  var ccc = $(this).attr('id');
  $("." + ccc).prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"));
  !$(this).prop("checked") ? $("." + ccc).prop("checked", false) : ''
})
$(".check").prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
  <input id="enableOne" class="checktype" type="checkbox" />1 разряд
  <br />
  <input id="enableTwo" class="checktype" type="checkbox" />2 разряд
  <br />
  <input id="enableNo" class="checktype" type="checkbox" />Нет разряда
  <br />
</div>


<div>
  <input class="check enableOne" id="1" type="checkbox" />1
  <br />
  <input class="check enableTwo enableOne" id="2" type="checkbox" />2
  <br />
  <input class="check enableOne" id="3" type="checkbox" />3
  <br />
  <input class="check enableTwo enableOne" id="4" type="checkbox" />4
  <br />
  <input class="check enableNo enableOne" id="5" type="checkbox" />5
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: для корректности задачи добавьте `.enableOne` ко всем чекбоксам во втором списке.

Comment: @teran добавил, но это уже мелочи. для ТС главное принцип.. ))

Comment: не плохо было бы и описание добавить

Comment: @C.Raf.T дак для того, чтобы ТС понял что в принципе можно добавить несколько классов :)

Comment: @teran согласен..))

Comment: Я, наверно, плохо задачу объяснил. Текст вопроса поправил.

Comment: @alegraft дополнил...